# How can I change an URL link in a deployed Journey Builder mail?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio, email-tracking

I have a running Journey Builder campaign, where one mail was already sent to subscribers. I would like to change a link, so the subscribers see the updated link in the already delivered email. 
In case of non Journey Builder mails at Email Studio/Tracking part when I select the mail there is a "Job Links" option where I can update links. I can't find this option in case of Journey Builder mails. 
Any ideas where to find this option?

Answer (score 1):

Changing links already in the subscribers mailbox is only possible for a single send.
In automations and journeys you have to pause, change links and restart that automation or republish that journey, but it will not change links in the mail already in the recievers inbox. You'll fix the issue for the remaining sends.

Actually, this is also the case if you use Einstein STO in a journey. As STO sends out the mail for the individual recievers in a span of 24 hours, you'd really not want to pause that journey, but if you don't you'll have the same link error for every send.

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_joblinks_overview.htm&type=5):

> If the email is associated with an automation or transactional send, you must stop the automation or pause the transactional send, change the link in the email, then republish and restart the automation or transactional send.

Hope some of this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Salesforce Support, currently there is no option for modifying links in delivered Journey Builder emails.

Answer (score -3):

1) Navigate to the Tracking tab. Find the Name for the send you would like to edit and click on it into the tracking report. In order to update links, the job itself must be complete or cancelled.

2) Within the tracking report, click on the Job Links tab. This will take you to a page showing the URL IDs and URLs within your email. Click on the URL ID for the link you would like to update. Note: If your email contains the same link in multiple places, there will only be one URL ID.

[image: lnik]

3) Next, you can update the URL as needed. The Preview section will show you the full URL. Users can also add parameters, if necessary. The platform will automatically add ?, =, and & in the parameter string where needed.

If your account is using the Web Analytics Connector, the URL parameters originally passed through will appear in this section. You can edit the parameters attached, even if they were applied via with Web Analytics Connector.

4) When you have updated the URL and parameters, click “Save.” SFMC will ask you to confirm your change.

5) After you confirm, the link update will be almost instantaneous, however, some subscribers may need to refresh the email or browser for the change to take place.

Note:
The update will only occur for the JobID you edit. The original email will not be updated. Additionally, if an update needs to occur for an email associated with a triggered send or automation, the send and/or automation must be paused and restarted in order for the change to take effect.

Salesforce documentation
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_joblinks_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: This won’t work for Journey Builder emails

Comment: @CodeRage you are right. Is there a way to work for Journey Builder emails?

Comment: I remember researching it in the past, but I don’t remember what I found out ;) So let’s see if someone can answer this one

Comment: @Duicug  Thanks for the suggestion, but I am afraid this works only for the normal mails. In case of Journey Builder mail tracking tab only "Overview" "Click Activity" and "Conversions" are available. 

The Update Job Links Overview documentation is tricky, it says "The email job status must be Completed or Canceled." Journey Builder mails can only have "Inactive" or "Active" status.